# Accessing VSTO method in VBA

Tags: c#, vsto

I am trying to call the Shared Add-in COM Registerd method from VBA.
I am using .NET Framework 2 and doing the code as it is in the post [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andreww/vsto-add-ins-comaddins-and-requestcomaddinautomationservice)

But when i build the add-in i get the error

> 'RequestComAddInAutomationService()' no suitable method found to override

Please can anyone help me on this?

Comment: It's called `.Net`, not dotnet.

Comment: I thought it was called **fullstopnet** or **periodnet**. **pointnet** would be ridiculous though.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that none of the base classes of the class that contains your implementation of [`RequestComAddInAutomationService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.addin.requestcomaddinautomationservice%28VS.90%29.aspx) contains a definition of that method.

Make sure that your class actually derives from `Microsoft.Office.Tools.AddIn`.

Maybe it gets clearer if you follow this walkthrough:

> [Walkthrough: Calling Code in an Application-Level Add-in from VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608614%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: It works fine in my machine but when i try to deploy this in other machine i get an error in the line automationObject.ImportData
Please help

Comment: @Sathish: Note that your assemblies must be registered on the target machine.

Comment: i am doing that via Setup deployment